# Spring Boot Error: type=Internal Server Error, status=500

Tags: spring, spring-boot, http, security, thymeleaf

I get an error when trying to open /users. I can’t figure out how to fix a mistake in my code. The error appeared after I added httpSecurity.

**Class Controllers:**

```
@GetMapping("/users")
 public String userPage(Model m) {
    m.addAttribute("Users", dao.findAll());
    return "users";
}
```

**users.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head th:include="layout::head"> </head>
    <body>
        <div th:include="layout :: navigationPanel"></div>
        <h1>User list:</h1>

        <div th:if="${#lists.isEmpty(Users)}">
        No users...
        </div>
            <table th:if="${!#lists.isEmpty(Users)}">
            <tr> <th>UserID</th> 
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Surname</th>
            <th>Login</th>
            <th>Password</th>
            <th sec:authentication="!isAuthenticated()">Edit</th>
            <th sec:authorize="!isAuthenticated()">Delete</th>
            </tr>
            <tr th:each="Users:${Users}">
            <td th:text="${Users.userid}"></td>
            <td th:text="${Users.name}"></td>
            <td th:text="${Users.surname}"></td>
            <td th:text="${Users.login}"></td>
            <td th:text="${Users.password}"></td>
            <td sec:authentication="!isAuthenticated()"><a th:href="@{/edit/__${Users.userid}__}">Edit</a></td>
            <td sec:authentication="!isAuthenticated()"><a th:href="@{/delete/__${Users.userid}__}" >Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
        <div th:include="layout::footer"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In @GetMapping you return `"users"` but your template name is `"user-list"`

and write `th:if={!Users.isEmpty()}` this one creates an issue. Do you check

whether you get the output from your database or not

Answer (score 0):

- Add the following dependency to your pom.xml

  [org.thymeleaf.extras.

  thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4.](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf.extras/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4/2.1.2.RELEASE)
- Change your html tag to  `<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4">`